# update UITableView sectionHeaderHeight at time of UIButton click in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Good day! My default tableview sectionHeaderHeight is 56. I want to update it when **sectionOpened** method gets called.This is the following code:

```
- (void) sectionOpened : (NSInteger) section
   {
            sectionHeight = @"YES";       
            getsection = section;     
            NSLog(@"Section Clicked: %ld",(long)getsection);

            SectionInfo *array = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:section];
            array.open = YES;
            NSInteger count = [array.category.menulist count];
            NSMutableArray *indexPathToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (NSInteger i = 0; i<count;i++)
            {            
                [indexPathToInsert addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
            }

            NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSInteger previousOpenIndex = self.openSectionIndex;

            if (previousOpenIndex != NSNotFound)
            {

                SectionInfo *sectionArray = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:previousOpenIndex];
                sectionArray.open = NO;
                NSInteger counts = [sectionArray.category.menulist count];
                [sectionArray.sectionView toggleButtonPressed:FALSE];
                for (NSInteger i = 0; i<counts; i++)
                {
                    [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:previousOpenIndex]];
                }
            }

            UITableViewRowAnimation insertAnimation;
            UITableViewRowAnimation deleteAnimation;
            if (previousOpenIndex == NSNotFound || section < previousOpenIndex)
            {

                insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
                deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
            }
            else
            {
                insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
                deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
            }

            [menulistTable beginUpdates];
            if(section==3 || section==4 || section==5) // this section has cells like submenu of a menu
            {
                menulistTable.sectionHeaderHeight = 20.0;
                [menulistTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                //[menulistTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            }
            [menulistTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathToInsert withRowAnimation:insertAnimation];
            [menulistTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:deleteAnimation];
            [menulistTable endUpdates];
            self.openSectionIndex = section;  
        }
```

But nothing happening. I also used **indexSetWithIndex:0**. Whats wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this to change Height:

```
[menulistTable beginUpdates];
menulistTable.sectionHeaderHeight = 20.0;
[menulistTable endUpdates];
```

**Edited:**

Take variable to set SectionHeaderHeight. Then place this code:

```
[menulistTable beginUpdates];
secHeaderHeight = 20.0;
[menulistTable endUpdates];

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return secHeaderHeight;
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: This one also helps me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499018/update-uitableview-sectionheaderheight-at-time-of-uibutton-click-in-ios/27499400